# Refering to a (sphynx autodoc generated) python method (:py:meth:) from a myst-parser markdown file?

Tags: python-sphinx, myst

I have a section of sphinx doc generated by the sphinx :autoclass: directive

I want to refer to the (docstring) generated doc of a python method from a mystmarkdown file

From

I have tried this:

{:py:meth:}`the_module.TheClass.the_method`

but the generated doc has no hyperlink, only highlighted `the_module.TheClass.the_method`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MyST documentation](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/index.html?highlight=autoclass#use-sphinx-ext-autodoc-in-markdown-files), you would use the following syntax.

Using the role:

```
{py:meth}`the_module.TheClass.the_method`
```

Using the Markdown syntax:

```
[the_method](the_module.TheClass.the_method)
```